# Function spaces from a geometrical viewpoint.

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, reference-request, topological-vector-spaces

I'm wondering whether there exists some geometrical theories of functional spaces. I mean; function spaces ($L^p$ spaces for example) are called topological vector spaces (TVS). I'm interested in whether there are some geometrical difference between each functional space or TVS (local<s>/global</s> convexness? Alexandrov curvature?)(I found vector space is always global convex, sorry! in 11/Dec '18).

And I'd like to take a look at some references about this kind of topic.

Anything will help, thank you!

Comment: There's no real need to include "reference request" in the title if you use the tag of the same name.

Comment: @Shan I'm sorry and thanks for your edit.

Comment: No apologies necessary. You're welcome :)

Comment: This is a whole branch of mathematics, it is called "Geometry of Banach spaces". It is a vast subject and it is impossible to resume it in an answer on Math.SE. If you are curious, you can consult some books on the subject; there are many. A standard reference is Lindenstrauss-Tzafriri.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you! I'd like to know, what kind of words or phrases titles may have for this kind of topic? (or this question is also too vast?)

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a small list of some geometric theory of Banach spaces, I hope you might find some of these results interesting.

- "Topological equivalence of all separable Banach spaces": Kadec proved that all separable Banach spaces are homeomorphic.
- "On the nonexistence of uniform homeomorphisms between $L^p$ spaces": Enflo proved the result for $1\le p,q \le 2.$
- "On nonlinear projections in Banach spaces": Lindenstrauss proved that for $p,q\ge 1$, if $\max(p,q) > 2$ then $L^p$ and $L^q$ are not uniformly homeomorphic.
- Maurey's "Type, cotype and K-convexity, in Handbook of the Geometry of Banach Spaces, Vol. 2": Type & Cotype is the method that is used nowadays to show that there's no isomorphism between different $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I found "nonexistence of uniform homeomorphisms between $L^p$ spaces" interesting.  Is "uniformity" condition important in this kind of theory?